# axis2 qname not fond for the package: org.hibernate.collection

Tags: apache-axis

I am trying to test an axis2 service by creating a client using wsdltocode and using adb databinding.

While testing it I get the following error. qname not fond for the package: org.hibernate.collection. Not sure what it means.

Also, is it possible to step through the service code using a IDE debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class had a List. Adding the list attribute to excludeProperties in services.xml fixed the problem.